# Alternating Least Squares Derivative

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, recommendation-engine, calculus

I'm trying to understand recommender systems that use ALS by reading up some content here : https://blog.insightdatascience.com/explicit-matrix-factorization-als-sgd-and-all-that-jazz-b00e4d9b21ea

I don't understand how the [image: Screenshot from the above link]

the second line of the equation , follows from the first line of the equation.

Moreover, x(u)_T seems to have dimensions : k x 1
and Y_T seems to have the dimensions k x m

In that case, how can these matrices be multiplied ?

Thanks!

Comment: Without knowing details of the named post: In the 2nd row, equality with 0 follows from minimizing the original loss function L, of which you gave the derivative. Dropping the summation over i follows the Einstein sum convention, which implicitly sums over all i here. The post mentions x_u^T as a row vector, thus having dimension 1 x k, and the matrix multiplication is valid.